# JAVA Json: Conflicting getter definitions for property

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I have a weird issue using Jackson in my Spring Boot project.

I have this class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClassDto {
    @JsonProperty("TSContact")
    private List<Contact> tsContact = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonProperty("LocationContact")
    private List<Contact> locationContact = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I try to map it to an other class using:

```
mapper.map(this, MyClass.class);
```

I get:

```
Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class model.dto.payload.MyClassDto]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "TSContact": model.dto.payload.MyClassDto#getTsContact(0 params) vs model.dto.payload.MyClassDto#getLocationContact(0 params)
```

What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: can you provide MyClass code?

Comment: You could try without Lombok and see if the error is different.

Comment: Jackson has problems with what are called "split properties" if they are defined in certain ways that are semantically accurate but not what it expects. Skip Lombok for this class and see what happens.